# Disproportionation of 2 KO₂ + 2 H₂O → 2 KOH + H₂O₂ + O₂

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

How is the following reaction a disproportionation reaction?

$$\ce{2 K\overset{-1/2}{O}_2 + 2 H2\overset{-2}{O} ->2 KOH + H2\overset{-1}{O}_2 + \overset{0}{O}_2}$$

In this, the OS are $-1/2$, $-2$, $-1$, $0$, respectively, but in disproportionation  the element$ O $both oxidizes and reduces. How do we know that this happens here? $\ce{KOH}$ may get oxidized, and $\ce{H2O}$ get reduced. How do we know the same compound has undergone both?

Comment: Compounds don't get oxidized or reduced; _elements_  do.

Comment: Note that it is adviced against MathJax or other intensive formatting in the title. Rather, plain text titles are preferred, if applicable. E.g."Disproportionation at potassium superoxide hydrolysis"

Comment: @Poutnik I will take a note of that

Answer (score 2):

The disproportionation happens to elements, not to compounds.

In this particular case, to the part of oxygen,

$$  \overset{\ce{2 KO2}}{ 4 \times -0.5}=  \overset{\ce{H2O2}} {2\times -1} +\overset{\ce{O2}}{ 2\times 0}$$

while the other part keeps the oxidation state constant:

$$  \overset{\ce{2 H2O}} {2 \times -2}=  \overset{\ce{2 KOH}} {2\times -2}$$

$\ce{H2O}$ does not get directly involved in disproportionation.

$\ce{KO2}$ oxidizes and at the same time reduces  itself.

This is the nature of isproportionation, which happens , if the particular compound of the element in the intermediate oxidation state has higher Gibbs energy then particular compounds of this element in higher and lower oxidation states. Therefore redistribution of oxidation states is thermodynamically preferred.

Typical cases are $\ce{2 Cu^{I}->Cu^{II} + Cu^{0}}$ and $\ce{2 Hg^{I}->Hg^{II} + Hg^{0}}$

Comment: Thanks , but I got confuse with if $\ce{K\overset{-1/2}{O}_2}$ is getting oxidised to $\ce{O2}$ and $\ce{H2\overset{-2}{O}}$ to $\ce{H2O2}.$

Comment: No, it does not. H2O does not get directly involved in disproportionation. KO2 oxidizes and at the same time reduce  itself. This is the nature of isproportionation, which happens , if the compounds with the element in intermediate oxidation state have higher Gibbs energy then compounds in higher and lower oxidation states. Therefore redistribution of oxidation states is thermodynamically preferred.