# Why do Cu⁺ ions spontaneously form copper metal and Cu²⁺ ions in solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, solutions, reduction-potential

> The standard electrode potentials for three reactions involving copper and copper ions are:
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \ce{Cu^2+(aq) + e- &-> Cu+(aq)} &\quad  E^\circ &= \pu{+0.15 V} \\
> \ce{Cu^2+(aq) + 2e- &-> Cu(s)} &\quad   E^\circ &= \pu{+0.34 V} \\
> \ce{Cu+(aq) + e- &-> Cu(s)} &\quad   E^\circ &= \pu{+0.52 V} \\
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Which statement is correct?
>
> **A**. $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ions are a better oxidizing agent than $\ce{Cu+}$ ions.
> **B**. Copper metal is a better reducing agent than $\ce{Cu+}$ ions.
> **C**. $\ce{Cu+}$ ions will spontaneously form copper metal and $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ions in solution.
> **D**. Copper metal can be spontaneously oxidized by $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ions to form $\ce{Cu+}$ ions.

I thought that because copper is more likely to get oxidised than $\ce{Cu+},$ it is a better reducing agent and thus **B** is the answer. But the given answer is **C**. Why?

Comment: See related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115660/disproportionation-of-2-ko%e2%82%82-2-h%e2%82%82o-%e2%86%92-2-koh-h%e2%82%82o%e2%82%82-o%e2%82%82/115662#comment218026_115662

Comment: @Poutnik - thanks, yes I did. But that does not explain why in terms of the standard electrode potentials involved. I'm having a hard time understanding how you could infer that from the SEPs given. Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Did you compare standard potentials of all 3 half reactions ?

Comment: as they are directly related to delta G via nF factor.

Comment: Strongly related; https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42855/why-cu-is-unstable-in-aqueous-medium

Comment: Take it as if Cu(I) had been 2 different compounds in one. One as oxidizing agent, the other as reduction agent. Compare potentials for their half reaction.

Comment: @Poutnik I got it!!! Thank you!!! Essentially, both reactions involving Cu+ have the lowest and highest SEPs respectively - so they have to be the strongest oxidizing/reducing agents - thus undergoing disproportionation. :)))

Answer (score 3):

Both reactions involving $\ce{Cu+}$ have the lowest and highest standard electrode potentials, respectively. Thus, $\ce{Cu+}$ has to be the strongest oxidizing/reducing agents, and therefore it undergoes disproportionation.

Because the formation of $\ce{Cu}$ has a higher SEP than $\ce{Cu+},$ it is more likely to get reduced and therefore is a better oxidizing agent — *not* a better reducing agent — than $\ce{Cu+}$ (which is more likely to get oxidized as it has a higher SEP).