# Cupric and cuprous copper

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, stability

Copper has two chlorides: $\ce{CuCl2}$ and $\ce{CuCl}.$
Copper reacts directly with chlorine to form a copper(II) chloride. Why doesn't it form copper(I) chloride? Is it because $\ce{CuCl2}$ is more stable than $\ce{CuCl}?$ I want a more foundational approach to answer this question.

Comment: Regarding stability of Cu+ see: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42855/why-cu-is-unstable-in-aqueous-medium

Comment: and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115674/why-do-cu%e2%81%ba-ions-spontaneously-form-copper-metal-and-cu%c2%b2%e2%81%ba-ions-in-solution

Comment: and who said copper(I) chloride is not formed? Wikipedia says that copper and chlorine directly reacts with each other to form copper(I) chloride at 450-900 C.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to look at this question.

On one hand, the heat of formation of $\ce{CuCl2}$ $(\pu{49.2 kcal/mol})$ is greater than the heat of formation of $\ce{CuCl}$ $(\pu{32.5 kcal/mol}),$ so if there is excess $\ce{Cl2},$ the product would naturally be the dichloride. On a kinetic basis, even with just a stoichiometric amount of chlorine $(\ce{1/2 Cl2}$ plus $\ce{1 Cu}),$ gaseous $\ce{Cl2}$ might produce a little cuprous chloride from bulk metal, but the product would be more finely divided and more likely to react, so the reaction would tend toward $\ce{CuCl2},$ leaving half the copper unreacted.

The electrochemical potentials reflect the same thing: in water, if you have enough oxidizing power to produce $\ce{Cu+}$ $(\pu{-0.52 V}),$ there is enough to go the rest of the way to $\ce{Cu^2+}$ $(\pu{-0.1 V}$ for $\ce{Cu+ -> Cu^2+},$ or $\pu{-0.34 V}$ for $\ce{Cu -> Cu^2+}).$